# How can i get the input from the user and display the sorted list

Tags: python, bubble-sort

How can i get 8 input from the user and sort it to ascending order using bubble sort algorithm i tried this code but the output is wrong the array is not in the sorted way and there is no errors the output i'm getting is [1]

```
def sort(num):

    for i in range(len(num)-1,0,-1):
        for j in range(i):
            if num[j]>num[j+1]:
                temp = num[j]
                num[j] = num[j+1]
                num[j+1] = temp

for t in range (8):
    nums=int(input("Enter Number: "))
    num=[nums]
sort(num)

print(num);
```

Comment: Hi, you don't say what's wrong. Please edit your question to say in what way the output is wrong.

Comment: Question edited @RegEdit

Comment: Did you try any debugging? Look at the *input* to sort.

Comment: `num` contains only one item when you pass it to `sort`, so the result also has only one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are doing wrong while taking input, each time the user input is taken num list is updated with new user input. I mean to say:

> user enter: 4
>
> num = [4]
>
> next iteration, user enter : 5
>
> now num becomes num = [5]

Hence, you have to do following modification, that is use append method of list in for loop.

```
num = []
for i in range(8):
    num=int(input("Enter Number: "))
    nums.append(num)
```